# How can one find 0?

Tags: complex-numbers

Suppose one of the three complex numbers, $w_{1},w_{2}$ and $w_{3}$, is $0$. How can one find
the one that is $0$ from equations, 
$$
\left|a_{1,i}w_{1}+a_{2,i}w_{2}+a_{3,i}w_{3}\right|=r_{i},
$$
 where $a_{1,i}$ , $a_{2,i}$ and $a_{3,i}$
are generic complex numbers, and $r_{i}$ is a real number, for $i=1,2,\cdots,6$?

Comment: What means "generic complex numbers"?

Comment: if the $c$ are generic, then one can relabel $z_1,z_2,z_3$ so how could there be an answer to your qestion?

Comment: Any help that can lead to a correct answer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: **How** "determine unique..."?

Comment: so generic means that given $r_1,\dots,r_6$ the system has a unique solution. So for any $r_1,\dots,r_6$ we have an 3x6 matrix C? But the $z_i$ are fixed?

Comment: @Blah: It means that for fixed 3 by 6 matrix $C$, for any $r_1$,$r_2$,...,$r_6$, there are unique z's satisfying the 6 equations. Let me know if you know the correct answer to my question. Thanks!

Comment: Unless this comes from an algebraic geometry question, please don't retag this with algebraic geometry - what you've put here is not, by itself, alg. geo.

Comment: So suppose for any fixed $C$ and any $r_1,\dots,r_6$ there is a solution $z_1,z_2,z_3$. How come you know that one of them is zero?

Comment: @Blah: Dear Blah, we suppose one of them is $0$. If none of them is zero, more equations would be needed to solve for them. Let me know if you know the correct answer to my question. Thanks!

Comment: Dear All, Let me give you all an example: for two complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$, if one of them is zero, we can find the $0$ from two equations by taking the quotient of one over the other. Now the question is how about 3 complex numbers and 6 equations? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In general, without knowing the values of $c_{j,i}$ and $r_i$, there is no way for you to solve this equation. For example, if you set $c_{j,i}=0$ for all $j$ and $r_i>0$, the equation has no solution.

If you know the solution exists, finding it will still be messy. You have a system of $6$ nonlinear equations for $6$ real variables. As far as I know, a non-numeric path to the solution is not viable.

Comment: Let me give you all an example: for two complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$, if one of them is zero, we can find the $0$ from two equations by taking the quotient of one over the other. Now the question is how about 3 complex numbers and 6 equations? Thanks!

Comment: Dear 5xum, it is true that some sets of $c_{j,i}$ does not determine unique $z_1,z_2$ and $z_3$, but most of them actually do. It does not ask to find the values of them, but just find the $0$. So can you just find $0$? Thanks!

Comment: Dear 5xum, if you don't know how to find 0 for most of them, please remove your answer, so that people know that is still an unanswered question. Thanks!

Comment: I did answer the question. I told you you have a system of $6$ nonlinear equations for $6$ real variables that you can only hope to solve using numeric means. The fact that no other answer appeared means that the community agrees with me.